# Is it bad practice to use NSArrayControllers programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa, nsarraycontroller

I'm wondering if there is any reason to not use NSArrayController programmatically.  All documentation and tutorials are geared towards having NSArrayControllers implemented in IB.

Is there any negative to doing so?

Comment: I'm trying to bind the contents of one NSArray to another NSArray, while applying a transformer between the two arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not at all. It may perhaps beat the purpose of using them, i.e. some kind of automation of the process of managing values, but of course you can create and use them in code instead of from a nib or xib.